# converting a DetailsView TemplateField cell value to short date string

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview, date-format, string.format

I have a detailsView whose date values in a cell are currently being displayed in longDateFormat, i want to convert all date values in this DetailsView to short date.

For example, instead of **6/1/2010 12:00:00 AM**, i want to display just **6/1/2010**

For a Gridview, i can achieve that by the code blow

```
  Protected Sub DetailsView4_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DetailsView4.DataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
            Dim cellDate As Date
            If Date.TryParse(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, cellDate) Then
                e.Row.Cells(i).Text = String.Format("{0:d}", cellDate)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

How can achieve the same with a DetailsView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved simply, if it is in template filed..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

or if it is not template field then

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="tDate" HeaderText="tDate" SortExpression="tDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False" />
```